# Clone into a specific cgroup with CLONE_INTO_CGROUP flag ,but don't change the real properties of task_struct

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cgroups

1、I try to use CLONE_INTO_CGROUP flag to Clone a task into a specific cpuset cgroup, then I found the child's cpuset is correct, but the real properties(task_struct->cpus_mask for me) are inherited from the parent process.It's not what I expected.

```
static void cpuset_fork(struct task_struct *task)
{
    if (task_css_is_root(task, cpuset_cgrp_id))
        return;

    set_cpus_allowed_ptr(task, current->cpus_ptr);
    task->mems_allowed = current->mems_allowed;
}
```

This code doesn't seem to have considered the CLONE_INTO_CGROUP flag;
is it a bug?

the information of CLONE_INTO_CGROUP is very little,may i use it with wrong way?

Comment: You should share the source code snippet which calls clone().

Comment: I don't use clone(). In fact，I keep a pointer to a specific group(CLONE INTO) and simulated the logic of CLONE_INTO_CGROUP, which looks like this

struct cgroup *cgrp;
cset = task_css_set(current);
kargs->cset = find_css_set(cset, cgrp);

in cgroup_css_set_fork()

Comment: I curious to know  if you found way to do